How to rotate pixel art keeping pixel aligment grid?
I'm working on a small project that requires me to draw character sprites, but the problem is that I'm not an artist but a programmer. I decided to generate images using Stable Diffusion using an extension that guarantees pixel perfect. The problem is that I can't generate an identical custom character every time, the AI ​​can't handle it. I decided that in such a case I would generate the character as accurately as possible in one throw (whole or divided into limbs) and use these limbs to animate the next sprites. Unfortunately, when rotating, the pixels (obviously) become crooked, so how can I deal with it? Is there a program that will allow me to rotate like that or one that will "pixelate" the image again by recalculating crooked pixels? Smash Studio seems good for a start, but it's too complicated and I don't have much time.
Here is what I want

Here what I get


One way to do this is by using GIMP which is free. It's also possible using software such as Photoshop, which isn't free unfortunately. Anyway the instructions below are for GIMP since anybody can get it.
The idea here is to first rescale and resample your graphic to a size where 1 visible pixel block in the graphic is equal to 1 actual pixel in the image.  This is what you are missing and it's why the rotation isn't working as you expect.
Here's how:

Count the width and height of the graphic in visible pixels (in your example its 18px wide x 15px high)

With the Crop Tool, crop the image to its exact size, leaving no gaps around the edges. Like this




Click Image > Scale image, set it to 18px x 15px, using Interpolation:None.  At this point you will need to zoom in on the image to see it clearly, as it will be very small.

Click Image > Canvas size, and increase the canvas size to 24px x 24px and centre the graphic

In the layers panel, add a new layer filled white, drag it to the bottom of the layers, and merge the two layers. Now you will have a single layer. Rename this layer "Original Layer".

Select the Rotate tool, and in the tool options set Interpolation:None

Duplicate the Original Layer, click on the image and rotate -10 degrees

Repeat step 7, increasing the rotation by -10 degrees* each time, and dragging the duplicated layer to the top of the layers, and continue repeating until you get to -90.


You should end up with 10 layers like this. I've renamed the layers to show the rotation angle of each frame. I've also renamed the bottom layer "Original Layer".  This is the layer you need to duplicate each time when doing the rotations in steps 7 and 8 above.


Click Image > Duplicate (so that you are working on a copy of the image)

This time, scale the image to 624px x 624px (or whatever size you need), keep Interpolation:None


Here's an example of the finished animation exported as a GIF. This example is 240px x 240px, but it can be whatever size you need.

*Note: Obviously if you need more steps use smaller angle increments for each rotation step, this will also require more frames.

Just a minor addition to highlight the purpose of duping the original: you start from the original image for each rotation in order to avoid "errors" from compounding between frames.

@Yorik - yes. precisely.

It's impossible to do this based on a single image alone (unless you turn it into multiple images in the format of one of the below approaches).
Most of the time when you see rotation like this it is probably using a 3D model with a post processing effect to make it look like pixel art. Alternatively, you could create a different raster image for each state of the rotation and then treat it like a sprite when wanting to rotate the object. There is software that can help you with either of these approaches.
